# who calls didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Tags: ios, loading

Which class or delegate should I sub-class to dig deeper into the call-stack of an IOS application startup sequence / loading sequence, specifically: Who calls this function?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Is there a way to sub-class the object calling this function so that I can see what's happening next after this function?

Comment: use the debugger if you want to dig into the call sequences.  in general, you should not subclass `UIApplication`, you should customize the application with the app delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read over the [UIApplication Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html),  [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidFinishLaunchingWithOptions%3a).